# LLDB watchpoint, p / Vim-lldb

Tags: c++, vim, lldb

I use LLDB as a vim plugin (the plugin name is '[vim-lldb](https://github.com/gilligan/vim-lldb)'). I created target and set breakpoints. All work fine except functions like `p, watchpoint` for examining variables. I get the message below.

```
(lldb) target create "test"
Current executable set to 'test' (x86_64).
(lldb) watchpoint set variable local
error: invalid frame
(lldb) p local
error: use of undeclared identifier 'local'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
(lldb) frame variable 
error: invalid process
```

Here's the test code complied with clang `clang -g -O0 test.cpp -o test`

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int local = testadd(3,4);
    printf("%d\n",local);
}

int testadd(int a, int b){
    return (a+b);
}
```

I thought `frame variable` should show a list of variables or some messages if there is nothing to show.

> All argument and local variables that are in scope will be shown when no arguments are given.

Please help...

Comment: It looks like you haven't run the target yet.  You are trying to access frames and local variables, but you don't have a live process yet.

Comment: Yup, You're right. Thanks a lot! I thought watchpoint automatically creates breakpoint.